# gcloud builds submit raises 403 error for `iam.serviceAccounts.get`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a Cloud Build I want to run from the command line. However when I try to run the build from my terminal, it raises this error:

```
$ gcloud builds submit --region=asia-east1 --config cloudbuild.yaml
Creating temporary tarball archive of 1 file(s) totalling 96 bytes before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://<REDACTED>.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) PERMISSION_DENIED: generic::permission_denied: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/<PROJECT_ID>/serviceAccounts/<MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>.
```

I have given the role `Service Account User` to both the above service account, and also to the user logged in to gcloud on my terminal (confirmed with `gcloud auth`).

Where else am I supposed to grant the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.get`?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Service Account User role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#iam.serviceAccountUser), It runs operations as the service account.
Lowest-level resources and you should grant this role to service accounts will have `iam.serviceAccounts.get`.

Try to give this command and try again

```
 gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
  --member="PRINCIPAL" \
  --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
```

And check this [Deployment permissions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configurationhttps://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) and check cloud build permissions from [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/iam-roles-permissions#predefined_roles).

Comment: No idea what "principle" is in this case

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle principle may be a user with email or a group,You can add from the [following](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview?&_ga=2.81713879.-1334537062.1666755371#concepts_related_identity).